# @Target Attribute value must be a class literal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on my first project with Spring and Hibernate and I would like to create a validator for an IP address.

To create the project I use IntelliJ. When I enter the code like this I get an error on the `@Target` annotation `Attribute value must be a class literal`

I do understand what this annotation has to do, but if I keep getting this error, it won't work.

I have looked at the documentation about custom constraints here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-simple and I have looked at several Stackoverflow pages, but I can't get this error solved.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;


/**
 * Created by johan on 17-5-17.
 */
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = IpAddressValidator.class)
public @interface IpAddress{
    String message() default "{ipAddress.invalid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Maybe `FIELD.class`?

Comment: @litelite Nope, already tried that. Then I get a message `Unknown class: FIELD`

Comment: [`FIELD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#FIELD) is a global constant, not a class.

Comment: @litelite What should I put there then? If I want to validate a field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You used the wrong `@Target`. You meant to use `java.lang.annotation.Target` but imported `org.hibernate.annotations.Target`. Change the first import to `import java.lang.annotation.Target` and it should work fine.

Comment: Life can be so easy sometimes if you know where to look. Thanks.

Comment: Same story! Thank you, mate!